# Write files in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I use JavaScript as scripting language to a Java program that I'm developing. I need to print in a file certain data; online I read that I need require a library.

```
var fs = require("fs")
```

But when Java compile the code returns this **error**:

> ReferenceError: "require" is not defined in lib.js at line number 1

I also tried to use `import` and `load()` but nothing changed.

So how can I write files with JavaScript used as script?

Comment: `require` only works in a Node.js environment.

Comment: @Xufox so what should i use?

Comment: How are you running the javascript?

Comment: @Rainb i use the script engine manager of java

Comment: How do you call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the Java standard library, so use their classes. For example:

```
var writer = new java.io.FileWriter("filename.txt");
writer.append("contents");
writer.close();
```